# Prestashop: move from local to live redirect to root

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I just moved my prestashop site from MAMP to live (godaddy) following this tutorial:
http://blog.arvixe.com/prestashop-migration-local-to-live/?WPACRandom=1452264803638
Everything seems to work fine till i change the tables:

```
PS_SHOP_DOMAIN: mydomain.com

PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL: mydomain.com

and in ps_shop_url:

domain: mydomain.com

domain_ssl: mydomain.com

physical_uri: /presta_test/
```

Now if i try to access to `mydomain.com/presta_test/`
i got redirect to `mydomain.com`!

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: did you tried to login into backoffice (admin), it works? Clear cache there on "Performance" tab

Comment: nope, cannot connect to admin. If i do: mydomain.com/presta_test/admin i got 404 page. But website is there because if i do mydomain.com/presta_test/README.md i can see the readme file

Comment: if you have finally installed prestashop, you can't have just "admin" directory it should be renamed

Comment: i see! First time i use prestashop, anyway yey! I was able to access my backend and after disable "Friendly URL" it works smoothly. Thank you very much for the support!

Comment: if you want to add it as official answer, i can check it

Comment: no problem, glad to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers of this tread:

Solution was to login in my admin:

```
mydomain.com/presta_test/youradminname
```

you can find `youradminname` in your file tree, is a directory that get renamed after first installation

Then

1. clear cache there on "Performance" tab
2. Disable Friendly URL

Comment: Can you mark your own response as answered please ?

Answer (score 0):

Also note that you should not edit domain name directly in the database. Your FrontOffice will redirect to your old domain name but your BackOffice will work with the new one.

When you connect to the BackOffice with another domain name it will display a `warning` asking you to update your configuration in `Preferences` > `SEO & URLs` > `shop URL`. When saving this configuration your `.htaccess` will be updated and the FrontOffice will work with the new domain name.

Comment: Really? All the tutorial i have found and also stackoverflow answers suggest to edit from the database :/